# haw can I do to get username proprite of my bean

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

Hello Stackoverflow community :)

there is a little time I work on a small jsf application.
Now I integrate spring security on my jsf ...I change my login page with spring security label "j_username"

```
<h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="User: * " />  
    <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" label="username" ***value="#{loginBean.username}"***/>  
    <h:message for="j_username" display="text" style="color:red"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password: * " />  
    <h:inputSecret id="j_password" label="password" required="true" />  
    <h:message for="j_password" display="text" style="color:red"/>

    <p:commandButton type="submit" id="login" value="Login" ajax="false"
        action="#{loginBean.doLogin()}" />
```

I tried to recover the username loginbean with value # {} loginbean.username on jsf page ..

because I have to use it to display it in a page that requires the knowledge of the user

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String username;  

    private String password; 

public String getUsername() {  
        return username;  
    }  

    public void setUsername(String username) {  
        this.username = username;  
    }  

    public String getPassword() {  
        return password;  
    }  

    public void setPassword(String password) {  
        this.password = password;  
    }  
public String doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        return null;
    }


    public String dologout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/login.jsf";

    }
```

> My problem is that the username property is not met when filling the
>   page .. it was full when I did not use the spring authentication
>   interface with these j-usernme and j_password

I have to do to get the name of this user! Please help me

Comment: So you are not getting username property on a page after submitting the login form, right?

Comment: Yes ,But I fixe the Problem Now

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="User: * " />  
    <h:inputText id="j_username" required="true" label="username" value="#{loginBean.username}"/>  
    <h:message for="j_username" display="text" style="color:red"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password: * " />  
    <h:inputSecret id="j_password" label="password" required="true"  value="#{loginBean.password}"/>  
    <h:message for="j_password" display="text" style="color:red"/>

    <h:outputLabel for="_spring_security_remember_me" value="Remember me: " />
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox    id="_spring_security_remember_me" />        
    </h:panelGrid>
```